# No se detecta link en HTML5

Tags: html5, enlace

Buenas tardes estoy teniendo el siguiente problema:

He formulado las listas que quiero que posean un enlace pero las mismas no funcionan ya que cuando ejecuto en la pagina el mousse no registra el hipervínculo cuando apoyo el mismo sobre él.

¿Alguien sabe que puede ser?

Desde ya muchas gracias, aquí dejo mi código:

```html
<body>
  <header class="encabezado">
    <!--aca ira el titulo,el ingreso y los logos -->
    <h1 class="titulo">bali underwear</h1>
    <ul class="logo">
      <li class="ingreso"><a href="ingreso.html"></a><i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i></li>
      <li class="carrito"><a href="./compras.html"></a><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i> </li>
    </ul>
    <nav>
      <!---el menu se compone por 4 enlaces-->
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#encabezado"></a>home</li>
        <li><a href="verano22.html"></a>sw22</li>
        <li><a href="intima.html"> </a>underwear</li>
        <!--<ul class="sub"> 
                      <li> <a href="pijamas"></a>pijamas</li>
                      <li><a href="interior"></a>interior</li>
                    </ul--->
        <li><a href="#contacto"></a>contacto</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 2):

Intenta de la siguiente manera, recuerda que el texto o lo que quieres que tenga el link debe ir dentro de la etiqueta a

```
<body>
  <header class="encabezado">
    <!--aca ira el titulo,el ingreso y los logos -->
    <h1 class="titulo">bali underwear</h1>
    <ul class="logo">
      <li class="ingreso"><a href="ingreso.html"></a><i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i></li>
      <li class="carrito"><a href="./compras.html"></a><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i> </li>
    </ul>
    <nav>
      <!---el menu se compone por 4 enlaces-->
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#encabezado">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="verano22.html">sw22</a></li>
        <li><a href="intima.html">underwear</a></li>
        <!--<ul class="sub"> 
                      <li> <a href="pijamas">pijamas</a></li>
                      <li><a href="interior">interior</a></li>
                    </ul--->
        <li><a href="#contacto">contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: y las imágenes tambien se ponen dentro del tag así: `<a>texto</a>` de lo contrario el enlace estar'a presente pero no visible